# Simply connected Kahler manifold without any effective divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Does anyone know an example of a simply-connected compact Kahler manifold without an effective divisor? Does anyone know a reference on this topic? Thanks!

Comment: There is a Torelli theorem for Kaehler K3 surfaces.  So, for a point in the period domain parameterizing $[H^{2,0}(X)] \in \mathbb{P}H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$  such that $H^{2,0}(X)$ is not orthogonal in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ to any given (nonzero) integer point of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, there is a corresponding Kaehler K3 surface $X$ that has no nonzero, integral $(1,1)$-classes.  Thus, these K3 surfaces have no effective divisors.